# Remote actor not responding to Identify?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm just messing around with some basics to learn akka remoting, and I'm running into an issue where my proxy class sends `Identify` messages to my backend, but never receives a response back.

I've verified that the backend receives messages sent to the `ActorSelection`, and I've seen a logging message where the backend actor says it will use xxx for serialization of the `ActorIdentity` messages.  Not sure where I'm getting it wrong.

Here is my proxy class:

```
package remoting

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorIdentity, ActorRef, Identify, ReceiveTimeout, Terminated}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class BackendProxyActor extends Actor {
  context.setReceiveTimeout(3.seconds)

  val path = createPath

  val backendSelection = context.actorSelection(path)

  println(f"BackendSelection is $backendSelection")

  override def preStart(): Unit = backendSelection ! Identify(1)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(1, Some(actor)) =>
      context.setReceiveTimeout(Duration.Undefined)
      context.watch(actor)
      context.become(active(actor))

    case ActorIdentity(1, None) =>
      println("Backend actor not available")

    case ReceiveTimeout =>
      backendSelection ! Identify(1)

    case msg: Any => println(f"Received $msg while identifying backend")
  }

  def active(backend: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case msg: Any => backend ! msg

    case Terminated(backend) =>
      println("backend terminated, going to identifying state")
      context.setReceiveTimeout(3.seconds)
      context.become(receive)
  }

  def createPath: String = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.load("frontend").getConfig("backend")
    val name = config.getString("name")
    val host = config.getString("host")
    val port = config.getString("port")
    val system = config.getString("system")
    val protocol = config.getString("protocol")
    f"$protocol://$system@$host:$port/$name"
  }
}
```

Here is my backend class:

```
package remoting

import akka.actor.{Actor, Identify, PoisonPill}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

class BackendActor extends Actor {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load("backend")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "stop" => self ! PoisonPill

    case msg: Any => println(f"Received $msg")
  }
}
```

My frontend class:

```
package remoting

import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}

class FrontendActor extends Actor {

  val proxy = context.actorOf(Props[BackendProxyActor], "backendProxy")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: Any => proxy ! msg
  }
}
```

and finally my App class:

```
package remoting

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Main extends App {
  val frontendConfig = ConfigFactory.load("frontend")

  val frontend = ActorSystem("frontend", frontendConfig)

  val frontendActor = frontend.actorOf(Props[FrontendActor], "FrontendActor")

  (1 to 20).foreach(i => frontendActor ! f"Msg #$i")

  frontendActor ! "stop"
}
```

My backend is being started in another process, and is run on port 2551, while my frontend is on port 2552.

Comment: With such `App` code, are you sure that your application doesn't terminate before the response to identify can be delivered?

Comment: yes, I removed my shutdown, so it just sits and runs indefinitely after the messages are sent

Comment: What is your "shutdown" that you removed, is the code above up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, I just had a `frontend.terminate` call at the end of the `Main` app